# Balance a number between three variables with bias

Tags: c#

I have a problem that i'm having issuing seeing a solution too. I have three variables A, B and C. what i'm needing to do is based on a Fourth number (input) balance a value of 100 between the three variables with a bias (I think thats the right word)

So, at the start A would be 100 and B and C would be 0. Then as Input is increased A would decrease and B would increase by the same value (so that A + B + C is always equal to 100). Then when B hits 100 increasing input would then increase C while decreasing B. The reverse would also be true so decreasing Input would make the value move from C > B > A.

I hope i've explained this well enough.

Edit : My attempt so far is this, in this case A, B and C are vCam.m_weight0, vCam.m_weight1, vCam.m_weight2

My problem with this is that i trips up when switching activeCam so the next jumps to 100 instantly. I beleive this is bad code, but i'm struggling to think of another way.

```
//Input is clamped between 0 - 100
private void HandleCameraSwitching(float newWeight)
{
    if (activeCam == 0)
    {
        vCam.m_Weight1 = newWeight;
        vCam.m_Weight0 = 100 - newWeight;
    }
    else if (activeCam == 1)
    {
        vCam.m_Weight2 = newWeight;
        vCam.m_Weight1 = 100 - newWeight;
    }
    else if (activeCam == 2)
    {
        vCam.m_Weight2 = newWeight;
        vCam.m_Weight1 = 100 - newWeight;

    }

    if (vCam.m_Weight0 == 100)
    { activeCam = 0; }
    else if (vCam.m_Weight1 == 100)
    {
        if (zoomingIn)
        {
            activeCam = 1;
        } else
        {
            activeCam = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(vCam.m_Weight2 == 100)
    {
        if (zoomingIn)
        {
            activeCam = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            activeCam = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a set of example values of A, B, and C with a few given inputs?

Comment: A, B and C will always be between 0 and 100 but the sum of them must always be 100, input is either 0.1 or -0.1

Comment: @Ben What is the problem you have? Please edit your question to include the source code you have and what the problem/struggle is you have.

Comment: Your right sorry. i was trying to generalize so i didn't have to explain stuff that wasn't relevant. but I went too general. The code i posted should hopefully clear that up.

Comment: Again your right sorry, starts at 0 not 1. so its m_Weight0, m_Weight1, m_Weight2

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Camera
{
    public Camera()
    {
        zoomingIn = true;
        m_Weight0 = 100;
        m_Weight1 = 0;
        m_Weight2 = 0;
    }
    public bool zoomingIn { get; set; }
    public float m_Weight0 { get; set; }
    public float m_Weight1 { get; set; }
    public float m_Weight2 { get; set; }

    public void HandleCameraSwitching(float newWeight)
    {
        if (m_Weight0 == 100) zoomingIn = true;
        else if (m_Weight2 == 100) zoomingIn = false;

        if (zoomingIn)
        {
            if (m_Weight0 == 100 || (m_Weight0 > 0 && m_Weight1 > 0))
            {
                m_Weight0 = 100 - newWeight;
                m_Weight1 = newWeight;
            }
            else if (m_Weight1 == 100 || (m_Weight1 > 0 && m_Weight2 > 0))
            {
                m_Weight1 = 100 - newWeight;
                m_Weight2 = newWeight;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_Weight2 == 100 || (m_Weight2 > 0 && m_Weight1 > 0))
            {
                m_Weight2 = 100 - newWeight;
                m_Weight1 = newWeight;
            }
            else if (m_Weight1 == 100 || (m_Weight1 > 0 && m_Weight0 > 0))
            {
                m_Weight1 = 100 - newWeight;
                m_Weight0 = newWeight;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`bool zoomingIn` changes when A or C equals 100

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are explaining is a specific scenario you want to implement. In programming terms this means building a model to represent your scenario.

Assuming at the start, A=100,B=0,C=0

Then define your update function. This is where you implement the details you mention

- a) When A hits 100 & there is input, start removing from A and add to B
- b) When B hits 100 & there is input, start removing from B and add to C
- c) When there is some output, remove from the last bucket and add to the previous bucket

If the logic is incorrect then please clarify

So for your update function, let's say Input() looks something like

(pseudocode)

```
Input() { 
    if((A==100)||(A > 0 && B > 0))
        { A -= 1, B += 1}
    if((B==100)||(B > 0 && C > 0))
        { B -= 1, C += 1}
}
```

My logic in this is that, if any bucket is 100 & you are adding, then remove from that bucket & add it to the next bucket. Logically we can deduce that there should never be a situation where a>0 & b>0 & c>0 so you can find which 2 buckets require the transfer if there is no value at 100 by looking at which 2 next to each other have values to transfer.

Reverse the logic for Output() (going backwards from c->b->a)

This might not be accurate, I haven't tested or executed the logic. Please correct it if it's (most likely) wrong or incomplete. These are the steps necessary to solve the problem though without outright building the entire model from scratch

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems to me that we can treat the three variables as a whole. It appears that we have a minimum value of `100`, and we can add a maximum of `200` to this value. To describe it better in terms of the variables, the table below shows the initial values of A, B, and C, followed by the user input, and then followed by the values after adding the input. The last column shows what we would calculate the "Total" value to be (i.e. the starting value of 100 plus the user's input):

```
A, B, C Values    Input    Ending Values    Total
--------------    -----    -------------    -----
100,   0,   0        1      99,   1,   0     101
 99,   1,   0        5      94,   6,   0     106
 94,   6,   0       30      64,  36,   0     136
 64,  36,   0      100       0,  64,  36     236
  0,  64,  36      -15       0,  79,  21     221
```

If you look at the table above, we can see a pattern:

- If the `Total` is less than `200`, then `C` is `0`, `B` is `Total - 100` and `A` is `100 - B`.
- If the `Total` is greater than or equal to `200`, then `A` is `0`, `C` is `Total - 100`, and `B` is `100 - C`.
- We can calculate the `Total` by testing if `A` or `C` is `0`, then using the formula above to calculate the total: `if (A == 0) Total = 200 + C; else Total = 100 + B`

We can then simply apply this logic in a method that takes in an input value:

- Calculate the Total
- Add the input value
- Set our three variables based on the new Total

In code this would look something like:

```
private static int A = 100;
private static int B;
private static int C;

private static void ProcessInput(int input)
{
    // Calculate current value new value
    var currentValue = C > 0 ? 200 + C : B > 0 ? 100 + B : 100;
    var newValue = currentValue + input;

    // We don't support values less than 100 or greater than 300
    if (newValue < 100 || newValue > 300) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    C = newValue == 300 ? 100 : newValue < 200 ? 0 : newValue - 200;
    B = newValue == 200 ? 100 : newValue > 200 ? 100 - C : newValue - 100;
    A = newValue <= 200 ? 100 - B : 0;
}
```

---

We can use the following helper methods and sample program to test it:

```
private static void ShowValues()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current values: A = {A}, B = {B}, C = {C}.");
}

private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ShowValues();
        ProcessInput(GetIntFromUser("Input a value: "));
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> A, B and C will always be between 0 and 100 but the sum of them must
>   always be 100, input is either 0.1 or -0.1 – Ben

I'd represent the values internally as integers that range from 0 to 1000.  To expose them publicly as a decimal number, convert to double (or whatever type you want) and divide by 10.  This will eliminate rounding errors as you Increase() and/or Decrease() many times.

Here's an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private CameraWeight cw = new CameraWeight();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = cw.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cw.Increase();
        label1.Text = cw.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cw.Decrease();
        label1.Text = cw.ToString();
    }

}

public class CameraWeight
{

    private int _m_Weight0 = 1000;
    private int _m_Weight1 = 0;
    private int _m_Weight2 = 0;

    public double m_Weight0
    {
        get { return (double)_m_Weight0/10; }
    }
    public double m_Weight1
    {
        get { return (double)_m_Weight1/10; }
    }
    public double m_Weight2
    {
        get { return (double)_m_Weight2/10; }
    }

    public void Increase()
    {
        if(_m_Weight0 > 0)
        {
            _m_Weight0 += -1;
            _m_Weight1 += 1;
        }
        else if (_m_Weight1 > 0.0)
        {
            _m_Weight1 += -1;
            _m_Weight2 += 1;
        }
    }

    public void Decrease()
    {
        if (_m_Weight2 > 0.0)
        {
            _m_Weight2 += -1;
            _m_Weight1 += 1;
        }
        else if (_m_Weight1 > 0.0)
        {
            _m_Weight1 += -1;
            _m_Weight0 += 1;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", m_Weight0.ToString("F1"), m_Weight1.ToString("F1"), m_Weight2.ToString("F1"));
    }

}
```